# How to pass different value from a CSV file for Each executor of Karate Gatling Job Executor setup?

Tags: karate, distributed

I have a maven based karate-gatling code setup and I am also using [JobExecutor](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/examples/gatling/src/test/java/jobtest/GatlingRunner.java) provided by Karate.
In our code we are using a CSV file which has list of usernames to pass one the username info in the code dynamically, now the problem is suppose I am using 10 Job Executor then each Job Executor is picking the same value from the CSV file for an iteration.

For Example: if a CSV file has username details as : User1. . .User300 then for the first iteration all 10 Executors will pick up User1 as the value!

Is there a way to ensure each Job executor picks up unique value ?

Comment: please note that we have stopped developing the distributed-testing that was experimental in Karate until version 1.4.0 since there was no appreciable usage, feedback or contributions. you may need to consider looking for alternative solutions or maintaining the code yourself.

Comment: Hey @PeterThomas can you please suggest some alternatives for this approach